# Is there a fread() equivalent for working with vector<char>s or char arrays?

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

I need to parse a file format, that's already stored in a `vector<char>`, and the closest method I could find that looks like it should work is `memcpy` - however, there doesn't seem to be any way of setting the offset of where that copy should start.

Am I just missing something here, or do I have to take the extra step to copy the data to a temporary vector first? Or is there a method that's better suited for this task?

**Edited for clarification**

Comment: When you say "parse" what do you mean by that? Read the vector as a string (why don't you use `std::string` to begin with) and parse out data from that?

Comment: By the way, if you have a vector (no matter of what data) and want to get item at "offset" X then it's simply `your_vector[X]`, and to get a pointer use `&some_vector[X]`.

Comment: Have you tried addition?

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of what you want to do? Perhaps give us the version where you "take the extra step to copy the data to a temporary version", so we can at least see the behaviour that you want. English is a lot less clear than C++ for describing a C++ program.

Comment: @joachim - thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! I have a file format in memory that I need to parse, and while I knew that my_vector.data() would give me a pointer to the first entry, I couldn't figure out how to offset it...like say, starting at position[x].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of copying data out of a `vector<char> vec;` is:

```
std::copy( vec.begin() + start_offset, vec.begin() + end_offset, dest );
```

Comment: I knew I *could* copy a range of chars from a vector at an offset, to a different vector, and then use its data method with memcpy, but that seemed like a (hopefully) unnecessary extra step.

Comment: @Digital_Utopia I think you misunderstand, I'm suggesting to use `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`. `dest` is where you are copying to (whatever you'd have as first argument to memcpy).

Comment: My apologies, I misread. I see what you mean now, and thank you for illustrating another way!

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector::data()` gives you the raw pointer to the data, which you can then use with `memcpy`

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

(in case that's what you want to do)

Or, better, see @Matt McNabb answer about using `std::copy`

Comment: Yes, I knew that - but the trouble was getting a position *other* than the first element in the vector. Apparently, I have a bit to learn when it comes to pointers and pointer addresses. :p

Comment: Yup, you are looking for **pointer arithmetic**: eg: `myvec.data() + offset`

Comment: That's also really nice to know - I didn't realize it was quite *that* simple.